# ng-src not showing up for my img array

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple image viewer webpage on gitpages but before I push the next group of images I want to condense all of my images into an array using angular.

The test I have made here uses only 4 photos that are in the same folder as every other file.(they are jpegs)

my js file is set up like this with a factory for the array and a controller.

```
angular.module('beamModule',[])
.factory('imageFactory', function(){
    return {
        getImages: function(){
        return ['beam1.jpg','beam2.jpg','beam3.jpg','beam4.jpg'];
        }
    }
})
.controller('Photos', function(imageFactory){
    this.images = imageFactory.getImages();
});
```

I don't think anything is wrong with this array but maybe I am overlooking something?

The HTML that I am using and the section that is giving me trouble when I check the developer tools is below.

```
<div class="imgcontainer" ng-controller="Photos as photosController">
    <img ng-repeat="src in photosController.images"
         ng-src="beamModule.js/{{images}}">
</div>
```

I am not sure if I am supposed to be using an ng-class attribute in the css or if there is something else that needs removed?

The developer tools are returning this value for each of the images (they are repeating just not showing)

```
<img ng-repeat="src in photosController.images" class="ng-scope">
```

Why is the ng-scope class being put in here and the ng-src is being removed?

EDIT FIXED

Ok to the person who answered so quickly and simply you are the real mvp here.
You said to change the ng-src="beamModule.js/{{images}}" to read {{src}} instead.

Once I tried this it still didnt work but then I checked the dev tools and noticed it was attempting to pull the files from the js file and not the actual file so I just changed it to this and now it works great! Thank you.

```
ng-src="{{src}}"
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ng-src="beamModule.js/{{src}}"` instead?

Comment: Ok, cool, nice that you got it working! :)

Answer (score 0):

The ng-src attribute needed to point to the repeat instead of the js file.

ng-src="{{src}}"